# my jquery form validation is not working as i hope it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some javascipt code here that validates a user form. When the user inputs the correct answer it tells them and gives them the link to the next question. At least, that's what it is supposed to do. When i click the form it reloads the page but it should not because i added return false.

the div tra holds 35
and the div usermsg is the user inputted value.

```
<script>
    $("#submit").click(function(){  
        var clientmsg6 = $("#usermsg").val();
        var rightanswer = $("#tra").val();
        if (clientmsg6<>rightanswer)
        {
        $("#confirm").html("<h2>Sorry, wrong answer.</h2>");
        }
        else
        {
        $("#confirm").html("<a href='#' onclick='play();' style='font-size:20px;' id='new1'>Click here for Question 2</a>");
        }
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Can you add your HTML, preferably with jsFiddle?

Comment: Another question: are you seriously storing right answers in your source code? (`$("#tra").val()`)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CMfHS/

Comment: Why not use a an input type="button", or better yet, a <button> element instead of a submit button if you do not want to submit the form?

Comment: the answer isn't in the source code, it gets loaded into it through jquery load

Comment: @Pieter were would be a better place to store the answers

Comment: Oh, I see. If you can load a file with jQuery, a user can do the same (copy the loaded url from source code and see the answer). It will be more safe to send the answer to a script with Ajax/jQuery  and return true/false.

Comment: @Pieter ok but im not sure how to do that

Comment: After submit, you send the answer with jQuery to a PHP-script which checks the answer. Let the script return true or false. Google 'post/get with Ajax jQuery' and you'll find a lot of examples.

Comment: ok ill do that thanks

Comment: im stupid, i remembered i already had this code in my signup page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
if (clientmsg6 != rightanswer)
```

not

```
if (clientmsg6<>rightanswer)
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent a form submission, you need to `return false` on the form itself instead of on the submit button.  Your code should become:

**HTML**

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
  <input id="usermsg" type="text" name="answer" />
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**JS** (please note the line where you have `clientmsg6`, you have a syntax error)

```
$("#myform").on('submit', function(){  
    var clientmsg6 = $("#usermsg").val();
    var rightanswer = $("#tra").val();
    if (clientmsg6 != rightanswer) { //This line was also wrong, should be != instead of <>
        $("#confirm").html("<h2>Sorry, wrong answer.</h2>");
    }
    else {
        $("#confirm").html("<a href='#' onclick='play();' style='font-size:20px;' id='new1'>Click here for Question 2</a>");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Alternatively, you can keep your existing code by changing your submit button to be just a plain old button, but you will lose the extra functionality of the user being able to hit the `enter` key and performing the same action.

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
  <input id="usermsg" type="text" name="answer" />
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .html(), try using .text()

Answer (score 0):

if #submit is a link tag otherwise use the form ID and the submit event

```
 $("#submit").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault() 

        ...
        ...
        ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach handlers once the document has finished loading.

Wrap your script in the following

```
<script>
$(function() {
  // script
});
</script>
```